# How to pass an entire object from parent to child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an object in which all properties need to be passed to the child-component. Passing them one by one was too slow.

Is there a similar approach in Angular to how it can be done in React?

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{name}}-{{age}}
    </p>
  `
})
export class DemoComponent {
  @Input() name: string = '';
  @Input() age: number = 0
}
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-use',
  template: `
    <p>
      use works!
    </p>
    <!-- Syntax similar to React, Pass in all at once, not one by one -->
    <app-demo ...demoInject></app-demo>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./use.component.css']
})
export class UseComponent {
  demoInject = {
    name: 'tom',
    age: 20
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you typically pass objects from the parent- to the child-component like this:

First the **parent-component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-use',
  template: `
    <p>
      use works!
    </p>
    <!-- Syntax similar to React, Pass in all at once, not one by one -->
    <app-demo [demoDto]="demoInject"></app-demo>
  `,
})
export class UseComponent {
    demoInject = {
        name: 'tom',
        age: 20
    } as DemoDto;
}
```

Then the **child-component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo',
  template: `
  <p *ngIf="demoDto">
    {{demoDto.name}}-{{demoDto.age}}
  </p>
`
})

export class DemoComponent {
    @Input()
    demoDto!: DemoDto;
}
```